# select and run a java class or call a method in a class using JFileChooser on an other class (GUI)

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have a file `A.java` containing a class `A` with a method `aMethod()` that is saved on a folder on the PC (not inside the package or workspace).

I have a `JFileChooser` on another class (`GUI`).
I want to be able to select class `A` and run it, or call `A::aMethod()` using the `JFileChooser`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is class `A` apart of the current application or a separate class (that is, is `A` within the classpath context of the running application)?

Comment: class A is in a different location. From the GUI class, the user selects from a JFileChooser class A. Then the name and directory of Class A is used to run it via a getRuntime().exec method(). System.out.print information from Class A is displayed on a textArea on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load class `A` into a custom class load so you can execute it.

There are a number of issues involved with this.  The first revolves around package names, the second revolves around actually calling the classes methods.

The following example basically uses a `URLClassLoader` to point to a directory of classes, these classes are layout our in there correct package structure.  The essentially provides the custom class loader with it's class path

```
try {
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new File("path/to/classes/").toURI().toURL()});
    Class<?> loadClass = classLoader.loadClass("dynamicclasses.TestClass");
    Object newInstance = loadClass.newInstance();
    System.out.println(newInstance);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The example also relies on the loaded classes `toString` method to return a result.  In my test, I simply dumped the classes class loader reference.

The second problem is a little more difficult to overcome.  You have two basic chooses.

1. You can define a common interface which is available to both the current runtime and the dynamically loaded class.  This allows you to cast the loaded class to some known interface which provides you with the ability to call the loaded classes methods (as you have established a contract between the two)
2. Use reflection to call the methods on the loaded class.

I prefer the first option, but it does mean if you change the interface, you need to compile both sides again.

Answer (score 0):

So I have made some progress. Not where I want to be but it's good...

My GUI has a button that does the following:

```
btnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            runFAQm();
        }
    });
```

the method called in the GUI when the button is clicked is runFAQm(). Method runFAQm() uses Runtime to run a java file that is saved in an other directory.

```
public static void runFAQm(){
try {                   
                String[] cmdArray = new String[2];
                // first argument is the program we want to open
                cmdArray[0] = "java";
                // second argument is a txt file we want to open with notepad
                cmdArray[1] = "FAQm";
                // print a message
                // create a file which contains the directory of the file needed
                File dir = new File(
                        "c:/Documents and Settings/AESENG/My Documents/MK/Selenium_Practice/workspace/TestCDM/src");
                // create a process and execute cmdArray and currect environment
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray, null, dir);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    textArea.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The java file (called FAQm.java) that is run via the runtime() inside the runFAQm() method, starts a Firefox browser. Of course I have sun Javac.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class FAQm {
static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.print("inside FAQm main" );      
}
```

**My problem now is that I can run Class FAQm from command line, and from eclipse, but it hangs when i run it from GUI by clicking on button. It hangs only when the Webdriver is initiated. If i comment out //static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); the program runs fine.**